# Spring Application start takes time to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When the application is started via shell. It takes time to start sometimes. The issue is relay inconsistent. I have tried both Xverify:none and also added lazy initialization parameter in the application.properties. But still facing this issue. What could be the possible cause of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Sure, each application needs time to start. Do you mean it takes too long? If I see that correctly the first info message which we can't fully identify because so much is blacked appears after about 2 seconds. It seems that's your app's info so Spring is probably doing a lot of stuff already (+ the JVM starting). Did you enable Spring's info or debug logs to see what happens before that log line you're showing? How big is your application?

Comment: @Thomas both screenshots are the same application. The initial start is the one that takes time. If you check the screenshot the first one takes 19 secs and the second one 1 sec. Once the spring logo appears everything works without any delay. I have enabled debug logs nothing gets printed before Spring. The application is a small one with a few components.

Comment: I see. In that case it might be your JVM taking some time, not sure how to debug this. It might be resource contention, OS-level locks etc. Did you check what your system is doing during those long startup times? Did you try another JVM?

Comment: @Thomas Issue us reproducible with a different  JVM.  how to check with one resource contention, OS-level locks etc

Comment: I'm not an expert on this and it might depend on your OS but I could imagine the following: 1) files the JVM wants to load are locked (could be antivirus scanning them or something else), 2) you're i/o blocked, i.e. the disk is busy or otherwise slow to respond, 3) much memory is taken and the OS needs to move it around to provide space for the JVM, 4) CPU is occupied

Comment: Even though it might not apply 100% to your case you could also have a look at this for some pointers: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/JRDTG/slow_start.htm#:~:text=2.1%20Possible%20Causes%20for%20Slow,on%20single%2DCPU%20machines).